# FLV PlayBack fullscreen button not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flvplayback

I'm building a flash app and using the FLVPlayback component, which for some reason isn't expanding to full screen when I click the button on the controls.

All my app has in it is the player, so I'm sure I haven't got any conflicting code of components elsewhere.

This is what I've got in my document class

```
flvPlayer.x = 0;
flvPlayer.y = 0;
flvPlayer.width = 640;
flvPlayer.height = 480;
flvPlayer.skin = "SkinOverPlaySeekFullscreen.swf";
flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0x999999;
flvPlayer.skinBackgroundAlpha = 0.7;
flvPlayer.skinAutoHide = true;
flvPlayer.source = "vid.flv";
addChild(flvPlayer);
```

Any suggestions as to what might be missing?

I'm 90% sure that I've had FLVPlayback working with this setup on a project in the past, so I'm inclined to think that there's a setting missing rather than the code being wrong.

I'm using Flash CS5 and ActionScript 3, with an external class for the AS code.

Answer (score 0):

You must create html wrapper file with parameter:

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
```

and then try press fullscreen button from html document

If you are usen Flash CS, there is html template in Publish settings with needed parameter inside.
Check [adobe fullscreen security](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c5d.html)